# selecting variable / selector and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I am currently trying to optimize a function I have and am looking to select both `$(this)` as well as `$(#selector)` or `varName` I have listed my code below to show an example, I have done some searching and cannot find anything specific.

```
$(varName, this).stop().animate({opacity : 1}, 'slow');
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a second parameter to `$()`, then jQuery will treat it as a context to search in.  What you need is to build up a jQuery object using the `.add()` method as show below:

`$("#selector").add(this).add(varName).stop().animate({opacity : 1}, 'slow');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may solves your problem.

$("#selector").add(this).add(varName).stop(true).animate({opacity : 1}, 'slow');

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
$(varName, this).stop(true).animate({opacity : 1}, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `varName` is something like `$('#foo')`...

```
$(this).add(varName).stop().animate({opacity : 1}, 'slow');
```